# Unity - clamping RotateAround function for camera?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Im making a game where the player rotates a camera(child of a camera holder) around a planet. I need to be able to clamp the position (and rotation) of the camera at certain points in time. Im using a RotateAround function and I was wondering if someone could help me to be able to clamp this? My code is below:

```
private void RotateCamera(Vector3 dragStartPosition, Vector3 dragEndPosition)
 {

     //normalised for odd edges
     dragEndPosition = dragEndPosition.normalized *planetRadius;
     dragStartPosition = dragStartPosition.normalized * planetRadius;

     // Cross Product
     Vector3 cross = Vector3.Cross(dragEndPosition, dragStartPosition);

     // Angle for rotation
     float angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(dragEndPosition, dragStartPosition, cross);

     //Causes Rotation of angle around the vector from Cross product
     holderTransform.RotateAround(planet.transform.position , cross, angle);

     EventHandler.instance.AddHiddenEvent(EventHandler.EventType.panCamera);
 }


 private static Vector3? GetMouseHit()
 {
     RaycastHit hit;
     int layer_mask = LayerMask.GetMask("Planet"); //raycasting on the planet
     if (Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit, Mathf.Infinity, layer_mask))
     {
         return hit.point;
     }
     return null;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Mathf.clamp() function.

```
public static float Clamp(float value, float min, float max);
```